# Specifying Columns in Excel ranges

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I need to specify the columns to use in the ranges for creating a chart. The number of rows will vary so they are not fixed.

this is the code I have,

```
int rowCountDRS = 172; //variable size changes

Excel.Range iChartRange;
iChartRange = iopsDBSheet.get_range("A2:A" + rowCountDRS, "D2:D" + rowCountDRS);
```

this generates the range but uses every thing from A2 to D rowCountDRS value, which is not what I am looking for, rather I want column Starting from A2 till rowCountDRS value and D2 till rowCountDRS value to be used to create my chart
but i am not sure how to specify due to varying rowCountDRS variable, be easiest if I could do something like

```
iChartRange = iopsDBSheet.get_range("A2:A172", "D2:D172");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting rowCountDRS - 172, do this:

```
int rowCountDRS = 2;
while (iops.DBSheet.get_range[rowCountDRS, "A"].Value != null
       && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(iops.DBSheet.get_range[rowCountDRS, "A"].ToString()))
{
    rowCountDRS++;
}
```

That checks down column A until it finds an empty cell, at which point is says "I've reached the end!" and rowCountDRS will be set to the last row containing data.

Cheers -